# Trying to conform to StringLiteralConvertible

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm running into a few oddities while trying to conform to StringLiteralConvertible:

```
class Person: StringLiteralConvertible {
    var name = ""

    init(name n:String){
        name = n
    }

    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType){
        name = n
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType){
        name = n
    }

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType){
        name = n
    }
}




var ironMan = Person(name: "Tony Stark")
var spiderMan: Person = "Peter Parker"
```

I implemented both the `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible` and the `UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible` protocols (whatever on Earth that means).

However I still got errors and had to provide definitions for both `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType` and `UnicodeScalarLiteralType`:

```
typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String
typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = String
```

Why did I have to provide this, if it's already in the standard header???

The compiler considered it still had the right to complain and forced me to add the `required` keyword to the inits, even though the definition of the protocols does not include the `required` keyword! Why????

The following code compiles, but I don't understand why the first version didn't compile!

```
class Person: StringLiteralConvertible {
    var name = ""

    init(name n:String){
        name = n
    }

    typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String
    typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = String

    required convenience init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType){
        self.init(name: value)
    }

    required convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType){
        self.init(name: value)
    }

    required convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType){
        self.init(name: value)
    }
}
```

Swift, if you like the compiler to yell at you, you're gonna love it! :-P

Comment: Have you looked here? http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/

Comment: The code in that post is outdated and won't even compile.

Comment: I'm also disappointed by how complicated it is to implement something that (implementation issues aside) is *not* a complex concept: You want to initialize an object with a string literal. (The present implementation actually forces some very bad code duplication!) That said, I'm sure the Swift team is aware of these limitations and Swift is an ever-evolving language so the good news is there's a good chance this will improve in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why typealiases:

The answer to your first question lies in the fact that Swift protocols that have associated types can be considered abstract, and need to be bound to a specific type.  Associated types are an alternative to using a more specialized approach like class MyClass : IsCompatibleWith<Int> {}.  I think the reason for this is to have common hierarchies, but this limitation also causes many other headaches.  No matter what though, it is reasonable and expected that you need to specify the type to which the protocol is bound.  In Swift, you do this by type-aliasing associated type to the one you want (String in your case).

Also note, that the associated type is not specified in the protocol, the protocol only specifies that you must define it.  That said, unless you have conflicting methods on your class, the compiler can generally infer the associated type (read this in the docs somewhere).

### Required initializers:

It appears that initializers specified in protocols are required by default / nature.  The documentation says that you can implement them as designnated or convenience, but that either way they are required:

> Class Implementations of Protocol Initializer Requirements
>
> You can implement a protocol initializer requirement on a conforming
>   class as either a designated initializer or a convenience initializer.
>   In both cases, you must mark the initializer implementation with the
>   required modifier:
>
> ```
> class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
> required init(someParameter: Int) {
> // initializer implementation goes here
> }
> }
> ```
>
> The use of the required modifier ensures that you provide an explicit
>   or inherited implementation of the initializer requirement on all
>   subclasses of the conforming class, such that they also conform to the
>   protocol.

From my reading though, it answers `what` but not `why`.